# Summation of column grouping by 2 columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I am looking for a fast and easy way to do the following in oracle sql.

I have two columns with many values each and a third column
and i need to sum up the third column by pair of values.

For example

My table would look like

```
a   c   20
c   a   30
a   b   10
b   a   15
c   b   1
b   c   2
```

and i want as an aoutcome something like this

```
a   c   50
a   b   25
b   c   3
```

Do you have any tips on that?

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You appear to want:

```
select least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2), sum(col3)
from t
group by least(col1, col2), greatest(col1, col2);
```

Comment: Thanks you so much!! it worls perfectly!!